Could reducing entanglement by unitary operations allow for FTL-communication? (and why not?)
About the closure: This Question is about why manipulating 1 particle of an entangled pair unitarily can’t cause measurable consequences on the other and how this manifests in the concretely described setup. The question this one got claimed as duplicate of and its answers not only don't contain any information about the setup described here, they also on a more abstract level do not even contain any mention of unitary time evolution and seem to generally apply to a completely different idea, namely measuring the state of 1 particle of an entangled pair and transmitting information to the other by collapsing the many particle state. I do not understand how this could be seen as a duplicate of the linked question.
Edit for clarity2: This proposal is very different from the classical EPR experiment in the aspect that measuring 1 particle to change the other is not part of this setup. Its all about unitary changes on 1 of the entangled particles, which lead to removal of the entanglement without measurement and thus measurable changes in the probability density of the other particle. I therefore changed the title, which previously contained “EPR”.
Edit for clarity: I am not asking whether faster then light communication is possible or not. From my information it is well established that it is not. However from my understanding the described setup would lead to instantaneous information transfer, so I am asking what exactly is wrong with my understanding of this setup as described in this question.
None of the other questions about FTL-information-transfer on this side, I have looked at, seem to address a sufficiently similar setup to answer this question. This includes the one suggested in the comments. Most of them just describe how doing a measurement on one of the entangled particles does not lead to observable consequences on the other, which is unrelated to my question as I am not trying to measure anything on the sender side.
So since this is not a duplicate I would kindly ask the people down voting this question to explain, what is wrong with it, so I can improve it, as right now I do not understand why you down vote.
To the actual question: For some reason, every time I think about the Einstein-Rosen-Podolsky-experiment my brain tries to construct ways for instantaneous information transfer. Usually it does not take me too long to see why they won't work, but in this case I am not sure.
So the basic idea is to instead of measuring one side to manipulate the other, we change one side unitarily to create a measurable effect on an interference pattern observed on the other side.
Lets first take a look at the interference measurement, that later is to be conducted with 1 of the EPR particles. For this I suggest to use a setup similar to a Mach-Zender-interferrometer, expect that the first beam splitter should be a polarizing one. We then add some additional components manipulating the phase and polarization on 1 path to ensure that for an incoming ray in a superposition of the 2 orthogonal polarization states we get the same behavior as in the Mach-Zender-experiment with one ray destructively annihilating.

Now my understanding would be that if we removed the polarization shifter P, the interference effect would vanish because then we have orthogonal Spin-states i.e.
$$||0\rangle|r_{D_1}\rangle - |1\rangle|r_{D_1}\rangle|^2 = ||0\rangle|r_{D_2}\rangle + |1\rangle|r_{D_2}\rangle|^2 = \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{1\setminus2}}|r_{D_{1\setminus2}}\rangle + \langle1|1\rangle \langle r_{D_{1\setminus2}}|r_{D_{1\setminus2}}\rangle \pm 2 \langle0|1\rangle \langle r_{D_{1\setminus2}}|r_{D_{1\setminus2}}\rangle = \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{1\setminus2}}|r_{D_{1\setminus2}}\rangle + \langle1|1\rangle \langle r_{D_{1\setminus2}}|r_{D_{1\setminus2}}\rangle := I $$
so equal intensity at both beam splitters, while with the polarization shifter we get
$$||0\rangle|r_{D_1}\rangle - |0\rangle|r_{D_1}\rangle|^2  = \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle + \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle - 2 \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle = 0$$
at Detector 1 and
$$||0\rangle|r_{D_2}\rangle + |0\rangle|r_{D_2}\rangle|^2  = \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{2}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle + \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{2}}|r_{D_{2}}\rangle + 2 \langle0|0\rangle \langle r_{D_{2}}|r_{D_{2}}\rangle = 2I$$
at Detector 2.

The idea is now to instead of the usage of the spin of the same particle to enable/disable the interference we use the state of a far away entangled particle to enable/disable the interference pattern. To do this we simply send 1 particle of our EPR pair into the above installation with the polarization shifter enabled, we will index this particle with $\uparrow$ and the other EPR-particle with $\downarrow$. So even though we shift the polarization for the upper EPR particle to have the same polarization in both paths of the upper apparatus, the state of the entangled other EPR particle will still be in different orthogonal states depending on the chosen way at the first polarizing beam splitter. Now if we do not manipulate the other particle I do expect the entanglement to destroy the interference pattern because:
$$||0\rangle_{\uparrow}|r_{D_1}\rangle_{\uparrow}|0\rangle_{\downarrow} - |0\rangle_{\uparrow}|r_{D_1}\rangle_{\uparrow}|1\rangle_{\downarrow}|^2  = \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle0|0\rangle_{\downarrow} + \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle1|1\rangle_{\downarrow} - 2 \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle1|0\rangle_{\downarrow} = \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle0|0\rangle_{\downarrow} + \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle1|1\rangle_{\downarrow} = I \neq 0$$
However if we manipulate the lower EPR particle in a way that independently of its initial polarization it ends up in the same state I would expect to see interference again.
$$||0\rangle_{\uparrow}|r_{D_1}\rangle_{\uparrow}|0\rangle_{\downarrow} - |0\rangle_{\uparrow}|r_{D_1}\rangle_{\uparrow}|0\rangle_{\downarrow}|^2  = \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle0|0\rangle_{\downarrow} + \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle0|0\rangle_{\downarrow} - 2 \langle0|0\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle r_{D_{1}}|r_{D_{1}}\rangle_{\uparrow} \langle0|0\rangle_{\downarrow} = 0$$

Now if this predicted behavior would be correct, it should be trivial to see how this could lead to faster then light information transfer. For each bit communicated one would of course have to make measurements on a whole bunch of EPR pairs to check if anything reaches detector 1 or not but that shouldn't be a problem, one can just exchange information about the planned procedure together with the EPR pairs, before separating them.

So the question is very simple: At what point exactly would the system behave differently then how I described it?

Does this answer your question? Quantum entanglement as practical method of superluminal communication

@Dale This does not answer the question, I am interested in understanding, what exactly is wrong with the setup, as it implying instantaneous information transfer indicates a misunderstanding of quantum mechanics on my side, which is what I am trying to find.

I'm not an expert in this, but the sentence that jumps out to me is "So even though we shift the polarization for the upper EPR particle to have the same polarization in both paths of the upper apparatus, the state of the entangled other EPR particle will still be in different orthogonal states depending on the chosen way at the first polarizing beam splitter."  Doesn't measuring the state of one entangled particle determine the state of the other?

@MichaelSeifert But the beam splitter doesn't do a measurement, it just creates a superposition state of particle polarized one way and diverted one way or polarized other way and diverted other way until we either measure the polarization or the position of the particle, that should still maintain the superposition state or shouldn't it?

@MichaelSeifert So we would have a superposition of particle $\uparrow$ diverted at beam splitter in direction $0$ and has polarization $0$ and particle $\downarrow$ in  polarization state $1$ as one state and particle $\uparrow$ diverted at beam splitter in direction $1$ and has polarization $1$ and particle $\downarrow$ in polarization state $0$ as the other.

@MichaelSeifert Measuring the state of one appears to determine the state of the other IFF you assume order of measurement matters. QM does not factor ordering in the equation. And in fact all delayed choice experiments are counter examples. The correct answer requires looking at the full context. And measurement order is never a factor. This example conflates measurement with detection. They can often be used interchangeably, but here it is a problem. If you don’t think a measurement occurs after a photon exits a PBS, try putting a 2nd PBS after that oriented different and see what happens.

Main answer
Rephrasing the core idea
You would like to start with the state
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|00\rangle - |11\rangle\right)
$$
Then apply a unitary $U$ transformation to particle 1 such that
\begin{eqnarray}
U |0 x \rangle &=& |1 x\rangle \\
U |1 x \rangle &=& |1 x\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
where $x$ (describing the state of particle 2) can be either $0$ or $1$.
If you could find such a unitary, then by performing this operation on particle 1, you would find the state transformed to
$$
U \Psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |0\rangle \left(|0 \rangle - |1\rangle\right)
$$
and then an observer looking at particle 2 would see an interference pattern. This would enable faster than light communication since the unitary could be applied at particle 1 at a spacelike distance from particle 2.
The problem
However, $U$ is not a unitary operator, since it is not one-to-one and thus cannot be inverted. So this is not a valid transformation of the quantum state (in the sense that it cannot be realized physically).
Another way to see this, is that if we form the density matrix $\rho=|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$, and take the trace over particle 2 to get a reduced density matrix for particle 1, we get a mixed state (this is shown in detail under "Original answer"). A unitary matrix cannot transform a mixed state to a pure state.
More generally, given two state vectors $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$, a unitary matrix cannot change the value of the inner product between them, $x = \langle A | B \rangle$. This follows from the definition of a unitary operator $U^\dagger U = 1$:
$$
\langle A | B \rangle = \langle A | 1 | B \rangle = \langle A | U^\dagger U | B \rangle = \langle A' | B' \rangle
$$
where
$$
|A'\rangle = U |A \rangle, \ \ |B'\rangle = U | B\rangle
$$
are the transformed state vectors.

Original answer
This is my original answer, which was based on misunderstanding the OP's idea, but I'm keeping it since it shows another interpretation of the general idea and a different way that would break down.
My attempt at rephrasing your idea
I believe the core of your idea is this:

to enable/disable the interference we use the state of a far away entangled particle to enable/disable the interference pattern.

If I could rephrase your idea in a simplified way (hopefully not overly simplified), then I believe this is essentially what you are saying.
Imagine a state like
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|00\rangle - |11\rangle\right)
$$
Then, if we naively ignore the first qubit (corresponding to the "control" particle), the state of the second particle is a superposition
$$
|\psi_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle \right) \ \ [{\rm INCORRECT}]
$$
Then if we send the second particle through an interferometer, we will see an interference effect due to the relative phases of $|0\rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$.
However, if we measure particle 1, and find it in state $|0\rangle$, then the full state collapses to
$$
|\Psi\rangle = |00\rangle
$$
Then the state of particle 2 is simply $|\psi_2\rangle=|0\rangle$, and there is no interference.
Therefore, you propose that by measuring particle 1, we can remove the interference pattern observed in an interferometer measuring particle 2, so we can know that particle 1 was measured "faster than light."
Where that breaks down
If I've understood you correctly, then the issue is that you haven't correctly understood what an observer will see for particle 2.
To understand the state of particle 2, it is best to use the formalism of a density matrix. The full density matrix for the whole system with particles 1 and 2 is
$$
\rho_{12} = |\Psi\rangle \langle \Psi| = \frac{1}{2} \left(|00\rangle \langle 00| - |00\rangle \langle 11| - | 11 \rangle \langle 00 | + | 11 \rangle \langle 11 | \right)
$$
Now the density matrix for an observer looking at particle 2 is obtained by tracing over particle 1
$$
\rho_2 = {\rm tr}_1 \rho_{12} = \frac{1}{2} \left(|0\rangle \langle 0 | 
+ |1 \rangle \langle 1 |\right)
$$
This is not a pure state -- it does not describe a superposition state where particle 2 is in a superposition of $0$ and $1$. Rather, it describes uncertainty in the state of particle 2. There is a 50% change particle 2 is in the $|0\rangle$ state, and a 50% chance it is in the $|1\rangle$ state. Crucially, neither the state $|0\rangle$ nor the state $|1\rangle$ will exhibit interference in an interferometer designed to look at the phase difference between the coefficients in a superposition of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. So observer 2 does not observe an interference pattern. They simply will see some particles taking one path in the interferometer, and other particles taking the other path.
A measurement of particle 1 will not change this picture for observer 2. They will still see particle 2 either in state $0$ or state $1$. Only if the observers later compare the measurements of particles 1 and 2 can they see the outcomes of their measurements were correlated, but this comparison can only take place within the bounds of the speed of light.


I think you misunderstood me: “if we naively ignore the first qubit” I am not sure if you suggested that, but I did not do that. I just described at the start how the interference apparatus would work for a single particle. Then I said that the existence of the entangled second particle would destroy the interference pattern.

What I am suggesting is reenabeling the interference pattern be unitary turning one of the possible states of the other particle(in your nomenclature that should be the first I think) unitarily into the other one. Your full pure state density matrix would then be of the form $$
\frac{1}{2} \left(|00\rangle \langle 00| - |00\rangle \langle 01| - | 01 \rangle \langle 00 | + | 01 \rangle \langle 01 | \right)$$.

And in that case your reduced density matrix $$
\frac{1}{2} \left(|0\rangle \langle 0| - |0\rangle \langle 1| - | 1 \rangle \langle 0 | + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | \right)$$ would be a pure state. So basically its about removing the entanglement by unitary time evolution without a measurement and thereby reenabling the interference on particle 2.

@Zaph So I think that corresponds to what I called "an alternative version" in my answer, right? In that case, as I said, the issue is that there is no unitary that does what you want.

For some reason I did not even see there was a second part ._. But yeah that does answer the question, I think. Though the followup question would be. Why is the described apparatus not able to produce that unitary transformation in the described way?

Also for the experiment it would be enough to unitarly turn it into something, that is not orthognal to the other state, does not need to be exactly the other. Is that also forbidden?

@Zaph I added the second part in an edit after rereading your question and thinking about what the polarization shifter was supposed to do, so it's possible that we just had crossed wires. Anyway, I think what happens is: the beam splitter sends a particle along one path with probability 50% and a particle along the other path with 50% and a flipped phase, but a superposition of the two polarizations goes down each path. (It's not like a SG apparatus where one polarization goes down one path and the other down a different path). So, the upper path will have something like (...)

(...) $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ (schematically), and the lower path will have $-|0\rangle - |1\rangle$. Then if you apply the polarization shifter to the upper path, it will interchange $1$ and $0$, but that will leave you with the same state $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$, not with $|0\rangle$.

A unitary transformation preserves the dot product between any two vectors, so if two vectors are orthogonal before the unitary is applied (have zero dot product), then they will also be orthogonal after.

What you described about both polarizations going both ways would be the case in the standard Mach Zender setup. But I explicitly changed the first beam splitter to be a polarizing one, so they really should have orthogonal polarization but no phase shift in this case.

Ok I will think about unitary operations and orthogonality. Could you perhaps edit your answer in a way that the part actually addressing the question is at the top and then mark the other part, if you want to keep it, as supplementary information not exactly addressing the question? I then would gladly accept your answer.

@Zaph I have updated the answer accordingly.

You write:

So even though we shift the polarization for the upper EPR particle to have the same polarization in both paths of the upper apparatus, the state of the entangled other EPR particle will still be in different orthogonal states depending on the chosen way at the first polarizing beam splitter.

If you are talking about systems evolving according to the equations of motion of quantum theory, then the state of one particle of an EPR pair doesn't change as a result of a change of the other particle.
Nothing happens to one particle of an EPR pair as a result of another particle of the EPR pair being measured. The state of the particle will not change. No measurement results of the particle will change. The observables of the particle will not change. The expectation values of measurement results will not change. The quantum equations of motion that describe photons and their interactions all imply that changes in the electromagnetic field propagate at or below the speed of light. Those equations of motion rule out any kind of FTL influence.
In quantum theory without any modifications such as collapse Bell correlations between entangled systems occur because locally inaccessible quantum information about the correlations is carried in decoherent systems and the correlations are established when the measurement results are compared:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

“Nothing happens to one particle of an EPR pair as a result of another particle of the EPR pair being measured.” This seems absolute reasonable to me, but in my mind measuring one side to change the other is not part of the proposed setup. In the part you quoted I am just pointing out, that, while manipulating 1 side the other side does stay, as it is, entangled with the path the first particle takes after the beam splitter, because that one is entangled with the polarization of the first particle, which is entangled with the  polarization of the second particle. No measurement needed.

@Zaph Again: what you quoted from alanf is correct (he is 100% correct). It doesn’t matter that you are fixated on the word “measured”. Any unitary transformation to P1 has no effect whatsoever on P2. You can also change phase of P1, send it to a mirror, rotate it, send it through fiber: nothing changes for P2. Note importantly that there is no more effect on P2 based on what happens with P1 any more than P2 influences P1. Timing/Ordering doesn’t matter. There is no causal direction with entanglement. You cannot say there is a sender and a receiver when order is meaningless.

@Zaph A change in one particle of the entangled pair doesn't change the other particle. As a result, there is no possibility of FTL communication.

Andrew pointed out in his answer, that the mechanism in the bottom side of the apparatus can’t possibly achieve, what it needs, while maintaining unitary, because it has to change the scalar product of the 2 possible states of the bottom EPR particle. While this is rather obvious once I thought about it, I was still wondering, at what part exactly of the described setup the unitarity would be broken.
The answer is, it does not get broken at all, everything in the setup described on the bottom could be realized by a perfectly unitary transformation. The issue is that even after aligning both rays into 1, the 2 possible 1 particle states of the bottom particle of the EPR-pair, would still be orthogonal and therefore the procedure would produce no measurable consequences for the other particle. I worked out the details on how that is possible in another post.

There are several relatively simple explanations as to why your diagram will not operate as you imagine.
First, all measurements on one part of an entangled system generate random outcomes. That is true regardless of the measurement performed on the other. No signaling possible that way. Only by comparing outcomes do patterns emerge.
Second, in your specific setup using a polarizing beam splitter at A: this simply performs a polarization measurement on any photon passing by - entangled or not. The result is a specific 0> or 1> outcome, and the photon proceeds on a specific arm of the apparatus. There is no ongoing superposition as you imagine.
Finally (at least for my answer): even if you alter the setup so there are non-Polarizing Beam Splitters to start: entangled photon pairs do not individually evidence the “usual” interference effects. Those effects only appear when there is coincidence counting. Which of course, means classical communication.
So… no FTL signaling. Just as you knew already.

Your first point seems to be just a rephrasing of the no signaling theorem which does not help understanding the concrete setup. Also note that in the setup a measurement is only ever performed on 1 side not on the other.
The argument of your last point I do not quite understand, you could use thousands of EPR pairs to transmit 1 bit, if none reach D1 the manipulation on the other side would be evident.

Now your second point might very well be the central issue, but I do not understand, why exactly you claim the beam splitter has to inevitably cause a collapse in the wave function. From my understanding a polarizing beam splitter acting on 1 particle, would just create a 1-particle entangled state between the spacial and the polarazation Hilbert spaces no collapse needed until you measure spin or position.

@Zaph Regarding second point:  Any photon going through a PBS will be polarized randomly in 1 of 2 orthogonal values. This is as basic as it gets. You have just measured its spin. If it was previously entangled on the spin basis, it no longer is. Is it theoretically possible to erase that measurement?  Possibly. But not using your setup.

So you are claiming, that there is no apparatus, that could create an entangled state of a photons position-Hilbert space with the same photons polarization-Hilbert-space, like a Stern-Gerlach-setup would do for position and spin of charge neutral spin-1/2 particles? I do believe that to be incorrect.

@Zaph Re 1st point: this is not a restatement of no signaling theorem. Every quantum measurement featuring probabilities has random outcomes. You can look all day long at either spot, and nothing will ever look different because… it’s random on the unmeasured side alone. Regardless of what you do on the other. Keep in mind that there is no such thing as “collapse” on one side causing some kind of collapse on the other or vice versa. This is well proven in many entanglement experiments- such as those featuring delayed choice. All you can make a statement about is the final context.

@Zaph No difference with other particles types. If you measure the entangled spin, it’s no longer entangled on that basis. The particles go one way or the other. Now, if you ask if photons can be entangled on both momentum and polarization bases, the answer is yes. They usually are with PDC. And in some cases you can measure on one basis without collapsing the other. But once you go through the PBS, you’ve basically switched to a typical Bell test, whether you wanted to or not.

@Zaph And to repeat what I said and Andrew has said: No change or measurement to 1 entangled photon will change the other’s probability density in any way that is observable without additional information.

I know that and your answer suggests, that you understand, that I know that, so please stop repeating it. The whole point of the question is to find, where exactly the problem with the setup lies.

Andrew rightfully pointed out, that the unitary transformation mapping both of the orthogonal 1 particle polarization states on 2 states non orthogonal can’t exist. You claimed the polarizing beam splitter would be the problem, which is really all I can take from your answer regarding the question, and maybe you are right. I don’t want to be disrespectful to your effort, but I need some time to think about, whether extending the superposion threw the pbm is somehow destroying unitarity or if that happens at another point.

@Zaph said “Its all about unitary changes on 1 of the entangled particles, which lead to removal of the entanglement without measurement and thus measurable changes in the probability density of the other particle.” If you send Photon 1 through a PBS, and then to outer space, that’s the end of its spin entanglement with P2. But that doesn’t translate to any observable of P2. As far as it knows, there is no “collapse”. And performing any operation on that P1 and recording it is the same. Entanglement does not operate as you assume/stated, and you will always object until you realize that.
